# Find email address for a domain using google?

Tags: email, google-search

Problem statement:

I want all pages which contains email addresses for a given domain. I am not sure what the query should be?

i tried something like -

@cnn.com

but this does not work .... any ideas?

Comment: I hope you are trying to do it for some good reason!

Comment: This question isn't programming related and [doesn't belong here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

Not perfect but occasionally this returns a gem 
Google Search for:
(email | mailto | contact) * cnn.com

You are asking for 'all pages on a domain' so in theory something like "site:cnn.com  (email | mailto | contact) * cnn.com" may work

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't possible using Google search. According to their help:

```
Generally, punctuation is ignored, including @#$%^&*()=+[]\ and other special characters.
```

http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=134479

Answer (score 1):

You can do that search on Bing, at least it worked for me

```
"@domain.com"
```

That should do the trick (It worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
site:domain.com "@domain.com"
```

Comment: Great, it works for me too

Answer (score -2):

This could be very helpful for spammers, so I think it is not possible to list all e-mail addresses just by searching them in Google :)

BTW. Do you really have a reason to do so? (Are you not another spammer?)

Comment: There are many legitimate reasons for asking this question beyond spam. Downvoted for lecturing the OP about their question.